# How can i read file pdf in AWS S3 with boto3 in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I would like to read .pdf files in S3 bucket, but the problem is that it returns formatted bytes,
Whereas if the file is in .csv or .txt this code works
What's wrong with .pdf files?

the code :

```
import boto3
s3client = boto3.client('s3') 
fileobj = s3client.get_object(
    Bucket=BUCKET_NAME,
    Key='file.pdf'
    ) 
filedata = fileobj['Body'].read()
contents = filedata
print(contents)
```

it returns :

```
b'%PDF-1.4\n%\xd3\xeb\xe9\xe1\n1 0 obj\n<</Title (Architecture technique)\n/Producer (Skia/PDF m99 Google Docs Renderer)>>\nendobj\n3 0 obj\n<</ca 1\n/BM /Normal>>\nendobj\n6 0 obj\n<</Type /XObject\n/Subtype /Image\n/Width 1424\n/Height 500\n/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB\n/SMask 7 0 R\n/BitsPerComponent 8\n/Filter /FlateDecode\n/Length 26885>> stream\nx\x9c\xed\xdd\xeb\x93$Y\x99\xe7\xf7'
```

another solution that i try but not work too:

```
import boto3
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader
from io import BytesIO

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(BUCKET_NAME,'file.pdf')
fs = obj.get()['Body'].read()
pdfFile = PdfFileReader(BytesIO(fs))
```

it's return :

```
<PyPDF2.pdf.PdfFileReader at 0x7efbc8aead00>
```

Comment: You cannot simply read PDF files - you need a PDF reader. So what you can do it get the data, save it in some `.pdf` file and then use a PDF reader to read.

Comment: If you really want to print it out in the terminal, consider searching for PDF to text conversion methods (you can do it in python as well directly)

Comment: So how can i do that?

Comment: Those "formatted bytes" are exactly what a PDF file looks like if you open it and view the contents directly. You have to have a PDF reader to convert that into the visual, human readable, display. This is why you can't open a PDF file with something like Notepad, you have to use a program like Adobe Acrobat. It sounds like you are trying to extract the text from a PDF file, so you should search for Python libraries that do that.

Answer (score 1):

Start by writing some Python code to access a PDF file on your local disk (search for a Python PDF library on the web).

Once you have that working, then you can look at reading the file from Amazon S3.

When reading a file from S3, you have two options:

1. Use `fileobj['Body'].read()` (as you already are doing) to obtain the bytes from the file directly, or
2. Use `download_file()` to download the file from S3 to the local disk, then process the file from disk

Which method to choose will depend upon the PDF library that you choose to use.

Comment: i try this before but don't work for me :/

Comment: Please tell us more than "but don't work for me". What PDF library did you use? What code did you use? What errors did you receive?